# assign values on one column to the specific column on other column using a common key

Tags: pandas

I have two dataframes as follows :

```
item_id   name     item_id label
-------------      ------------- 
11         a        11       1 
11         b        12       2 
12         c        13       3
13         d        14       4 
14         e
14         e
```

I would like to assign the values of label column to the column `id` on the `left` dataframe.
I tried using the `merge` but I guess I made a mistake while joining and not getting the expected result.

```
Expected result:

item_id    name    label
------------------------
11         a         1
11         a         1 
12         b         2
13         c         3
14         d         4
14         d         4
```

Comment: Is `id` a column of the dataframes or their index?

Comment: it is a column. I should have changed the name of the column. Consider it as a `item_cd`

Comment: Please check out the duplicated answer. In case it does not respond to your needs, reopen your question with more details

Comment: I have checked the same duplicated answer. But it did not work for me.

Comment: @RicS Thanks for your reply. I have updated the question.

Comment: `df1.merge(df2, on='item_id', how='left')` should work just fine

Comment: @RicS Somehow the left merge removes the duplicates. I would like to have all shown in the expected results

Comment: For how the left join it's constructed, it's impossible that it removes the duplicates. Check out if there is something wrong in your data, otherwise reopen the question with more details or your exact dataframe (if it is possible to share it)

Comment: Thanks @RicS. I have created a separate post with all the details. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66811137/mapping-values-from-one-column-to-the-values-from-another-column-in-a-pandas-dat/66812466#66812466