# Mapping values from one column to the values from another column in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes `df1` and `df2`.  I would like to get the `pred_label` from `df2` to get assigned to the corresponding `bar_cd`in `df1`.   there are some duplicate `bar_cd` like `1006040448`  in df1. I would not like to lose them due to the merge operation. I tried left merge but ended up getting null values for `pred_label`

Both df1 and df2 have similar `bar_cd`.

If I would like to assign the `pred_label` to df1 which approach would be suitable. I would appreciate your advice. Is there a way to map `pred_label` to `bar_cd` in `df1`
I have referred to the article  [Merge 101][1]. But it did not work for me.

```
df1:

     bar_cd     actual_label
0   1006036382  3.0
1   1006040448  3.0
2   1006040448  3.0
3   1006044789  3.0
4   1006044789  3.0

df2: (consider this as master file for mapping)

         bar_cd     actual_label  pred_label
133494  1006036382  3.00           3.00
180288  1006040448  3.00           4.00
122732  1006044789  3.00           4.00
38225   1006808018  1.00           2.00
205799  1008874962  2.00           1.00




expected result:

     bar_cd     actual_label      pred_lable 
0   1006036382  3.0               3.0
1   1006040448  3.0               4.0
2   1006040448  3.0               4.0
3   1006044789  3.0               4.0
4   1006044789  3.0               4.0
... ... ...


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101
```

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a `dictionary` with your bar_cd as as your keys and pred_label as your values from `df2`, and then `map` it back to `df1`.

```
d = dict(zip(df2.bar_cd,df2.pred_label))
df1['pred_label'] = df1['bar_cd'].map(d)
```

---

```
df1
       bar_cd  actual_label  pred_label
0  1006036382             3           3
1  1006040448             3           4
2  1006040448             3           4
3  1006044789             3           4
4  1006044789             3           4
```

Comment: Is creating a dictionary efficient if I have 300k unique `bar_cd` ?
My question should have been more precise regarding the unique number of `bar_cd`

Comment: all the values for `pred_label` are coming out to be `Nan`. Is there anything missing?

Comment: Sorry for the delays in replying. The code works well for me. Are you sure the bar_cd on the 2 datasets are the same?

Comment: It seems so. The number of unique values in both dataframes is same.  Is there a way to verify if both dataframes have same `bar_cd` ?

Comment: I tried `df1.bar_cd.unique() == df2.bar_cd.unique()` it shows me a lot of false values. But I think my approach of checking this condition is wrong.

Comment: check for common ones using a list comprehension -> ```[i for i in df1['bar_cd'].unique() if i in df2['bar_cd'].unique()]```. This will give you a list of the common ones.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
# Separate duplicate values
dup = df1.duplicated(subset=['bar_cd'], keep='last')
dup = dup.sort_values(by=["bar_cd])

rem = df1[~dup]
rem = rem.sort_values(by=["bar_cd])


# Reorder df2
df2 = df2.sort_values(by=["bar_cd])

# Merge each df with df2
new_df1 = pd.merge(
    right=rem,
    left=df2,
    how="right",
    on=["bar_cd"],
)

new_df2 = pd.merge(
    right=dup,
    left=df2,
    how="right",
    on=["bar_cd"],
)

new_df = pd.concat([new_df1, new_df2])
```

Comment: sorry it does not work. Output gives `Nan` values for `pred_label`

Comment: Didn't see that there are duplicated keys in df1. Updated my answer accordingly.